# need to query all the records that are within 7 days to each other

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to get the `servicetag`, `ActivityID` based on `created_on` date.

Here the criteria is that I need to retrieve all the records that were created within 7 days time.  I need to filter the same for more than 100 records.

I was able to filter between two dates.  But, I am hitting a brick wall on how to when I realized that I might have to compare the created time for each record and retrieve data that is within 7 days to each other.

```
create table TicketInfo(Created_on datetime, 
                        ActivityType varchar(255), 
                        ServiceTag varchar(255), 
                        ActivityID varchar(255));  


ServiceTag       ActivityType         ActivityID        Created_on 

  FFF3FF          call-inbound         A-45879        2018-08-15 09:15:00  
  FFF3FF          email-inbound        A-45879        2018-08-13 09:15:00  
  FFF3FF          email-inbound        A-1234         2018-08-05 09:15:00  
  Z345FG          call-inbound         A-2345T        2018-08-03 09:10:00
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Date and time functions vary greatly between different DBMS. So please tag the one you're using. But please only tag the one you're using not just randomly any.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your requirement but I guess that's what you are looking for: 

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.TicketInfo ti1
JOIN   dbo.TicketInfo ti2
ON     ti1.Created_on - 7 <= ti2.Created_on
AND    ti1.Created_on > ti2.Created_on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your db is mysql then below filter works

```
   select * from TicketInfo where Created_on>= DATE_SUB(Created_on, INTERVAL 7 DAY) and
    Created_on<=Created_on
```

If Sql Server then it shuld be

```
   select * from TicketInfo where Created_on>= dateadd(day,-7,Created_on) and
    Created_on<=Created_on
```

But if postgrey sql then it should be

```
     select * from TicketInfo 
    where Created_on>= Created_on- interval '7 days'
    and  Created_on<=Created_on
```

Comment: hi..thanks for the response.. i am usning MySql. Unfortunately, i am still not getting the desired result. I want data for the records where the difference between two dates is 7days. need to compare one record with the next record.    for example: among dates 2018-03-05, 2018-03-07, 2018-03-19.. i need to get data for records with dates 5 and 7..19 should be ignored as the difference is not 7days..

Comment: @AbhiRamchallapalli can you please tell me our dbms name

Comment: i am using mysql